# How to get Current week and current date record wp query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, post-meta

i have add new **show date as post meta** in my custom post type i want to get only current week show and today show . please help for write code(Query) do this. i dont know how to compare current date with post meta value and get **current week and today record**s using wp query please help

Comment: In what format is the meta date information stored?

Comment: dd--mm--yyyy format